# Java Get Default UI Colors

Tags: java

How could I find out the default selection color in a JList for example?
Where are these colors are stored?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Swing components you can get and set the default colors in the application wide [`UIDefaults`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIDefaults.html) provided by the [`UIManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html):

```
UIDefaults defaults = javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults();
defaults.getColor("List.selectionBackground");
defaults.getColor("List.selectionForeground");
```

Answer (score 9):

[UIMManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) lists all the defaults in a nicely formatted GUI.

Comment: Haha, you wrote this? It's a pretty awesome tool.

Comment: If you're just looking for a list of variable names you can use http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/11/all_ui_defaults_names_common_java_look_and_feels_windows_mac_os_x_and_linux

Answer (score 7):

```
JList.getSelectionForeground();
JList.getSelectionBackground();
```

for that particular box.

Usually they will be read from `SystemColor.textHighlight` and `SystemColor.textHighlightText`
at the time the UI is created.