# Extend the system look and feel in a Swing application

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, look-and-feel

I want to use the system look and feel for a Swing application. So I used the `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` method which works pretty fine.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

But, now I want to change all the `JButtons` of the app (in all my `JFrames`, `JDialogs`, `JOptionPanes`, `JFileChoosers`, etc.) and only the `JButtons`. So I would like to know how can I extend the system look and feel to keep it for all components except the `JButtons` (and the `JPanels`, which I want with a gray background).

Thank you.

Comment: Also see [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)

Comment: Cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3705571/230513). Please try to focus your very broad question; an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for these pointers. I'll take a look in a few hours. Sorry but no SSCCE to provide. My question is general because I really have no idea to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I extended the system look and feel like this:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
UIManager.put("ButtonUI", "com.my.package.MyButtonUI");
UIManager.put("Panel.background", Color.green);
```

With `MyButtonUI`:

```
public class MyButtonUI extends BasicButtonUI {

    public static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 24;

    private static final MyButtonUI INSTANCE = new MyButtonUI ();

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent b) {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) c;
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        final int buttonWidth = button.getWidth();
        if (button.getModel().isRollover()) {
            // Rollover
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.green, 0, BUTTON_HEIGHT * 0.6f, Color.red, true);
            g2d.setPaint(gp);
        } else if (button.isEnabled()) {
            // Enabled
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.red, 0, BUTTON_HEIGHT * 0.6f, Color.gray, true);
            g2d.setPaint(gp);
        } else {
            // Disabled
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.black, 0, BUTTON_HEIGHT * 0.6f, Color.blue, true);
            g2d.setPaint(gp);
        }
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, buttonWidth, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        super.paint(g, button);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) c;
        if (isInToolBar(button)) {
            // Toolbar button
            button.setOpaque(false);
            super.paint(g, button);
        } else if (button.isOpaque()) {
            // Other opaque button
            button.setRolloverEnabled(true);
            button.setForeground(Color.white);
            paint(g, button);
        } else {
            // Other non-opaque button
            super.paint(g, button);
        }
    }

    private boolean isInToolBar(AbstractButton button) {
        return SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JToolBar.class, button) != null;
    }
}
```

Note: I higly recommend this link: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/ (from Robin)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make your own button class, e.g. CustomButton, which extends JButton, make all your changes and use this instead of the standard JButton. This way you can use both custom and standard buttons - if you change your mind and want to add a standard JButton somewhere ;)

Comment: I could. But how could I use this `CustomButtom` in a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`?

Comment: If you use the UIManager then the custom buttons will appear in the message dialog. If you use a CustomButton class, forget about showMessageDialog() and just make your own JDialogs displaying your own buttons and whatever you want.

Comment: how would i add a colour to the custom button and the regular one? well actually im using a Label but what property do you assign the colour too as all there would be in properties is Label.foreground how do you set a property for a custom class